# Is the canonical morphism $\mathbb A^n \to\mathbb A^{n-1}$ a projective morphism?

Tags: tag-removed

Let $\mathbb A^n$ be the n-dimensional affine space over a field K (algebraically closed if that makes it easier), so $\mathbb A^n= \text{Spec }K[x_1,...,x_n]$, and $\mathbb A^{n-1}$ the (n-1)-dimensional analog. The inclusion $K[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]\to K[x_1,...,x_n]$ induces a map $\mathbb A^n \to\mathbb A^{n-1}$. Is this a projective map?

Comment: For it to be projective (in particular proper), the image of a closed set should be a closed set. Look at the case $n = 2$. Then the map $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ with coordinates $x,y$ and $x$ resp. The map on rings you wrote corresponds to the projection $(x,y) \mapsto x$. Now, $\mathbb{A}^2$ has the closed set $xy = 1$, the image of which is all of $\mathbb{A}^1$ except the origin. Since this isn't a closed set, the map isn't proper. Similarly, you can rewrite the standard counterexample for larger $n$. (Btw, maybe you want to tag this "algebraic-geometry").

Comment: maybe you meant to ask if this were an affine map?  (it makes less sense to ask about projective maps when the spaces are all affine.)

Comment: It makes sense, it's just the same as talking about finite maps.